# How to pass arguments to a cocoa-touch app

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode

I noticed in main.m it appears to recognize parameters like any c program. How can I pass arguments to the app?

Answer (score 1):

You would never need to call main with arguments in a cocoa touch application.  If you read the code you'll see that main is used to simply load the cocoa touch app when the user touches the application icon.  You can effectively pass arguments to your app by creating a plist file and reading it.

Comment: So why does main look the way it does?

Comment: Not sure I understand the question....if you mean why have argc and argv defined, its really there as a convention.....you'll see that apples code is very tight in that way..